# Nodejs: Do singleton variables get overwritten do to async requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var Singleton = {
    Sdata : "some data",

    modify-data : function(data, callback){
            Sdata = data;
            callback(Sdata);
    }
}
```

Here, does Sdata get overwritten by two different requests accessing the function modify-data at the same time?

Can it be averted like following:

```
var Singleton = {

    modify-data : function(data, callback){
            var Sdata = data;
            callback(Sdata);
    }
}
```

here, does a new var Sdata get created every time? And if two requests access modify-data at the same time, does it create a new instance of Sdata for each?

Comment: what's the point of having a `Sdata` variable ? `var Sdata = data; callback(Sdata);` is equivalent to `callback(data);`

Comment: well, the code above is just to get the idea of how async requests can change a variable sData in singleton. And how the request1 might get the response of request2, since request2 might overwrite the response of request1 (when request1 and request2 are concurrent requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods are also first-class objects in javascript. So, if modify-data is called, its scope should be encapsulated. So, to answer your questions, yes and yes.